# My ESP32 connects to the Hive MQTT broker, but when I try to establish a connection on the websocket client website, I lose connection

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, esp32

My code successfully connects an ESP32 to a Hive MQTT broker. The only problem is that when I try to connect on the Hive websocket client website, I lose connection and my code trys to establish a new connection. This occurs because it sets "client.connected()" back to false which runs the reconnect() function again. I do not know why it is doing this. To run my code and see what I mean you may have to create a cluster on the Hive MQTT website and add the details for the cloud and wifi details to the code. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    #include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
    #include <esp_crt_bundle.h>
    #include <ssl_client.h>

    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <PubSubClient.h>

    /****** root certificate *********/

    static const char *root_ca PROGMEM = R"EOF(
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
    TzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxKTAnBgNVBAoTIEludGVybmV0IFNlY3VyaXR5IFJlc2Vh
    cmNoIEdyb3VwMRUwEwYDVQQDEwxJU1JHIFJvb3QgWDEwHhcNMTUwNjA0MTEwNDM4
    WhcNMzUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WjBPMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJu
    ZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2ggR3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMTDElTUkcgUm9vdCBY
    MTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK3oJHP0FDfzm54rVygc
    h77ct984kIxuPOZXoHj3dcKi/vVqbvYATyjb3miGbESTtrFj/RQSa78f0uoxmyF+
    0TM8ukj13Xnfs7j/EvEhmkvBioZxaUpmZmyPfjxwv60pIgbz5MDmgK7iS4+3mX6U
    A5/TR5d8mUgjU+g4rk8Kb4Mu0UlXjIB0ttov0DiNewNwIRt18jA8+o+u3dpjq+sW
    T8KOEUt+zwvo/7V3LvSye0rgTBIlDHCNAymg4VMk7BPZ7hm/ELNKjD+Jo2FR3qyH
    B5T0Y3HsLuJvW5iB4YlcNHlsdu87kGJ55tukmi8mxdAQ4Q7e2RCOFvu396j3x+UC
    B5iPNgiV5+I3lg02dZ77DnKxHZu8A/lJBdiB3QW0KtZB6awBdpUKD9jf1b0SHzUv
    KBds0pjBqAlkd25HN7rOrFleaJ1/ctaJxQZBKT5ZPt0m9STJEadao0xAH0ahmbWn
    OlFuhjuefXKnEgV4We0+UXgVCwOPjdAvBbI+e0ocS3MFEvzG6uBQE3xDk3SzynTn
    jh8BCNAw1FtxNrQHusEwMFxIt4I7mKZ9YIqioymCzLq9gwQbooMDQaHWBfEbwrbw
    qHyGO0aoSCqI3Haadr8faqU9GY/rOPNk3sgrDQoo//fb4hVC1CLQJ13hef4Y53CI
    rU7m2Ys6xt0nUW7/vGT1M0NPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNV
    HRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBR5tFnme7bl5AFzgAiIyBpY9umbbjANBgkq
    hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAVR9YqbyyqFDQDLHYGmkgJykIrGF1XIpu+ILlaS/V9lZL
    ubhzEFnTIZd+50xx+7LSYK05qAvqFyFWhfFQDlnrzuBZ6brJFe+GnY+EgPbk6ZGQ
    3BebYhtF8GaV0nxvwuo77x/Py9auJ/GpsMiu/X1+mvoiBOv/2X/qkSsisRcOj/KK
    NFtY2PwByVS5uCbMiogziUwthDyC3+6WVwW6LLv3xLfHTjuCvjHIInNzktHCgKQ5
    ORAzI4JMPJ+GslWYHb4phowim57iaztXOoJwTdwJx4nLCgdNbOhdjsnvzqvHu7Ur
    TkXWStAmzOVyyghqpZXjFaH3pO3JLF+l+/+sKAIuvtd7u+Nxe5AW0wdeRlN8NwdC
    jNPElpzVmbUq4JUagEiuTDkHzsxHpFKVK7q4+63SM1N95R1NbdWhscdCb+ZAJzVc
    oyi3B43njTOQ5yOf+1CceWxG1bQVs5ZufpsMljq4Ui0/1lvh+wjChP4kqKOJ2qxq
    4RgqsahDYVvTH9w7jXbyLeiNdd8XM2w9U/t7y0Ff/9yi0GE44Za4rF2LN9d11TPA
    mRGunUHBcnWEvgJBQl9nJEiU0Zsnvgc/ubhPgXRR4Xq37Z0j4r7g1SgEEzwxA57d
    emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    )EOF";

    /*** WiFi Connection Details ***/
    const char* hotspotName = "";
    const char* password = "";

    /*** MQTT Broker Connection Details ***/
    const char* mqttServer = "";
    const char* brokerUser = "";
    const char* brokerPassword = "";


    WiFiClientSecure mqttClient;
    PubSubClient client(mqttClient);

    void setupWifi(){

      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("\nConnecting to: ");
      Serial.println(hotspotName);

      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(hotspotName, password);

      while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){

        delay(100);
        Serial.print("-");

      }

      Serial.print("\nConnected to: ");
      Serial.println(hotspotName);

      randomSeed(micros());
      Serial.println("\nWiFi connected\nIP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    }

    void reconnect(){

      while(!client.connected()){

        Serial.print("\nConnecting to: ");
        Serial.println(mqttServer);

        String clientId = "ESP32Client-";   // Create a random client ID
        clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
        Serial.print("Client ID: ");
        Serial.println(clientId);


        if(client.connect(clientId.c_str(), brokerUser, brokerPassword)){
          Serial.print("\nConnected to: ");
          Serial.println(mqttServer);
        }
        else{
          Serial.println("\nTrying to connect again");
          delay(5000);
        }

      }

    }


    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(115200);
      delay(10000);
      setupWifi();
      mqttClient.setCACert(root_ca);
      
      client.setServer(mqttServer, 8883);
    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

      if(!client.connected()){
        reconnect();
      }
      client.loop();
      
    }
```

I expected "client.connected()" to stay true once I had established a connection.

Comment: I don’t see anything in your code having to do with websockets.

Comment: You connect to the Hive MQTT websocket client by specifying the host, port, clientId, username, and password as I did in my code. I omitted these details in the sample code I provided as I did not want to share them. I can connect the ESP32 to the websocket perfectly. The issue arises when I try to connect to the websocket on the website. Then I lose connection.

Comment: "I can connect the ESP32 to the websocket perfectly"; that's not what your current code does (it's not using websockets; [`pubsubclient` does not support](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/issues?q=is%3Aissue+websockets) websockets directly - it may be possible with [this](https://github.com/areve/WebSocketStreamClient)). What clientid are you using in the web client? (if you are using the same one that your arduino used then what you are seeing is expected, the server will drop any existing connections with the same client ID).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help and I will look into this. I was just a little confused as I was definitely getting a message which said "Connected to: mqttServer" so I am just wondering how I received this message if it was not connecting to the websocket.

Comment: If you are using port `8883` then you are probably not using WebSockets ([by default](https://docs.hivemq.com/hivemq/latest/user-guide/listeners.html#tcp-tls-listener) `8883` is MQTT over TLS). Note that your code can connect using native MQTT and send messages, which can be received via a client that has connected using WebSockets (the main reason for using WebSockets, other than in the browser, is because port 443 is commonly permitted through corporate firewalls).